# Redefining an included definition in terms of itself

Tags: scheme, racket

**All of the following is a basic example of a more complex problem:**

In another file called secondary_file.rkt, I have the following definition:

```
(define work_hours '(8 8 8 7 5))
```

Now let's say I want to change everything in work_hours by adding 1, but still want to keep the name.

In imperative programming, I would just say `work_hours[i] = work_hours[i] + 1`.
Obviously that can't be done in a functional language, and I also want to do this without using `set!`

So something like this:

```
(define work_hours_copy work_hours)
(define work_hours (function_to_add_one_to_all_work_hours work_hours_copy ))
```

So essentially make a copy of work_hours `work_hours_copy`, and then redefine work_hours using work_hours_copy has a parameter.

But this won't work because I'll get the error:

```
dictionary: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
```

Comment: What about redefining ie this way: `(define work-hours (map 1+ work-hours)`?

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). *Why* do you need to do this? (It is generally better to pass things as function arguments than to rely on global values.)

Comment: you seem to be using an undefined identifier `dictionary` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track that you want something like [`parameters`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/parameterize.html?q=parameter#%28tech._parameter%29). A parameter is called like a function, but its value can be  (dynamically) set.

You use `make-parameter` to make a new parameter, and generally use `parameterize` to temporarily  set the value.

Now you can do something like:

```
(define work-hours (make-parameter '(8 8 8 7 5)))
```

Now when you reference `work-hours` directly, you get a function:

```
> work-hours
#<procedure:parameter-procedure>
> (work-hours)
'(8 8 8 7 5)
```

But when you put it in a `parameterize`, you can (temporarily) change the value based on its dynamic scope:

```
> (parameterize ([work-hours (map add1 (work-hours))])
    (work-hours))
'(9 9 9 8 6)
```